# open link from UIWebView into Safari (iphone)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mobile-safari, hyperlink

ok rather than try to explain my problem in text, watch this little video i recorded
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwb55jnZI6w

and here is the code for the detail view controller (the page where the webview is)

detailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MWFeedItem.h"
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>  {
    MWFeedItem *item;
    NSString *summaryString;
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *contentLabel;
    //IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *textScroller;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MWFeedItem *item;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *summaryString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *contentLabel;
@end
```

detailViewController.m

```
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "NSString+XMLEntities.h"

typedef enum { SectionHeader, SectionDetail } Sections;
typedef enum { SectionHeaderTitle, SectionHeaderDate, SectionHeaderURL } HeaderRows;
typedef enum { SectionDetailSummary } DetailRows;



@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize item, summaryString, titleLabel, contentLabel;


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)contentLabel shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {

    NSURL *requestURL = [ [ request URL ] retain ];
    // Check to see what protocol/scheme the requested URL is.

        return [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];
    return NO;
    // Auto release
    [ requestURL release ];
    // If request url is something other than http or https it will open
    // in UIWebView. You could also check for the other following
    // protocols: tel, mailto and sms
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*if (item.date) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        self.dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:item.date];
        [formatter release];
    }*/

    if (item.summary) {
        self.summaryString = [[[item.summary stringByStrippingTags] stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace] stringByDecodingXMLEntities];
    }

        titleLabel.text = item.title ? item.title : @"[No Title]";
        [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        //dateLabel.text = dateString ? dateString : @"[No Date]";
                            // Summary
    NSString *HTMLData = summaryString;
    [contentLabel loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.feed43.com/1515171705611023.xml"]]];

    //Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
    //CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,9999);

    //CGSize expectedLabelSize = [summaryString sizeWithFont:contentLabel.font 
    //constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
    //lineBreakMode:contentLabel.lineBreakMode]; 


    //adjust the label the the new height.
    //CGRect newFrame = contentLabel.frame;
    //newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    //contentLabel.frame = newFrame;
    [textScroller setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    [textScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
    textScroller.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
    textScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
    textScroller.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //return titleLabel;
    //return dateLabel;
    //return contentLabel;

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return NO;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

note: even though it says "contentLabel" it is a UIWebView. it is left over from old versions

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implement `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
Then you can do something like this :

```
NSURL* url = [request URL];
if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the only things i had to change were the second "webView" in that delegate implementation to "contentLabel" (the name of my webView) and then put "return YES;" outside the curly brackets of the code you showed me. thank you!