# How to detect a click event in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableView that loads content into a UIWebView like this:

```
//MainViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      CGRect bounds = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] applicationFrame ];
      UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
      UIWebView *htmlView = [ [ UIWebView alloc ] initWithFrame:[scrollView bounds]];
htmlView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,280,360);
      NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [htmlView loadRequest:requestObj];

    scrollView.contentSize = [htmlView bounds].size;
    [scrollView addSubview:htmlView];    
    [detailsViewController.view addSubview:htmlView];


    [htmlView release];
    htmlView = nil;

    [scrollView release];
    scrollView = nil;


   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
   [detailsViewController release];

}
```

All of the remote content that gets fed to the UIWebView comes from a web service that I wrote. The first screenshot is what is presented when a word is selected from the list view titled "Glossary"

[image: Detail view controller with UIWebView HTML content]

This all is great until you follow a link, in this case clicking on the "frame" link in the UIWebView content. The new content gets loaded but I need to tell the nav bar that the UIWebView has changed so I can at least change the white title text to match the new content. What UIWebView methods should I implement and where should they go?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201264/open-link-from-uiwebview-into-safari-iphone/3201364#3201364

Comment: Thank you!  I implemented the method per the link you posted. Does that method get called automatically  when the event occurs or do I need to call it explicitly?

Comment: It gets called automatically by the webview if you set the view controller to be the webview delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your view controller to be the UIWebView's delegate, then implement

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Hmmm. Thought that would of done it. Added UIWebViewDelegate to my view controller's header file: @interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate>
{...}
 and implemented the methods in the .m file but after clicking a link, execution is not getting inside the implemented methods as evidenced by my breakpoints inside those methods never being hit....