# Tracking navigation in WKWebView doesn't work for button click

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swift5

I am trying to catch a button click in my web view. Button "action" if I can say so, triggers certain url... I am not really able to catch this moment through WKNavigationDelegate. webview is set like this:

```
 lazy var advertWebKitView: WKWebView = {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webConfiguration.preferences = preferences
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return webView
    }()
```

I am trying to catch that button click like this:

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        guard let urlAsString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString.lowercased() else {
            return
        }
        
        if urlAsString.range(of: "...") != nil {
           
        }
    }
```

but this method doesn't trigger when button is clicked.

On android, it works and its done like this:

```
@Override
        public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
            if (url.equals("...")) {
                finish();
            }
             //...
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
        }
```

what would be equal method and a way to track navigation correctly through wkwebview?

EDIT:
if there is some info needed about the webpage structure or so, please ask for details and I will add that too. I just didn't know which info may be relevant or helpful.

The button html looks like this:

```
<a class="lc-button lc-button--light" href="/close">OK</a>
```

Also one interesting thing is, that I have tried to use my code on other sites and navigation delegate methods were triggered correctly. Which leads me that problem is with our site and its html code or something about how the page is loaded after button is clicked, maybe...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect a click event in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196585/how-to-detect-a-click-event-in-a-uiwebview)

Comment: @KirilS. It doesnt help cause its about UIWebView, rather than WKWebView.

Comment: Please show the code for the button and its action in the web UI.

Comment: @SanthoshR Currently I only have button html code. I guess is not much of a help, but if more info is needed, about what technology they used on FE, and how page is reloaded / loaded, I can provide you that tomorrow.

Comment: Did you try to move `decisionHandler(.allow)` to the end of the function?
Maybe also try to use the delegate function `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` instead

Comment: @ndreisg The problem was that none of delegate methods weren't actually firing cause of FE implementation.

Comment: So you found the solution? Can you maybe write an answer then?

Comment: I wrote it in a comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244259/3402095. I dont have more info cause it was problem / solution on a site, not in mobile app. @ndreisg

Comment: According to your comment on the answer below I think that your delegate function actually fired but you set your breakpoint after the guard statement. Since the request didn't have an absolute url the function didn't pass the guard so it returned.

Comment: They are not fired for sure. I have put breakpoint on the very beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RedirectTo instead of LinkTo in react router for redirecting to /close

Comment: I will check this with FE developer as soon as I can... I mean it works now, but he solved like I said in one of the comments.

Comment: He just told me its not React router, but rather Reach router.

Comment: My guess is that Link-to just moves the user to that route. Using href or redirect-to means redirecting him to a new route that would fire the delegate.

https://reach.tech/router/api/redirectTo You can check this link for more details

Comment: Yeah it worked when he used <a> tag with href attribute... Anyway, cause. this is most close answer to what solved the problem, I will accept this one.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my previous comment with the link for using redirect To. Check that if that works

Answer (score 2):

I am using this myself and it works, it is slightly different than what you are trying until now but the right equivalent to the Android method.

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let requestURL = navigationAction.request.url, requestURL.pathComponents.contains("...") {
//Do your things 
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Comment: The thing is delegate method doesnt fire up at all, so whatever I put in there it doesn't matter in this case. Also we solved this... It was Front End thing... They changed reach-routers <Link to='/close'>... with <a href="https://myserverurl/close"> and it worked. I dont really know why it worked, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First set delegate in `viewDidLoad`,

```
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

You can catch where your button is navigating you to by implementing
**WKNavigationDelegate** function, `didFinish navigation`

```
extension YourViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if let currentURL = webView.url{
            if self.urlString == currentURL.absoluteString{
                  print(self.urlString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said all that was implemented, but any method wasn’t triggered.

Comment: @Whirlwind I have updated answer, please check answer again, have you set up navigation delegate?

Comment: Its all there, navigation delegate was set. Also the problem is solved, it was issue with our website.