# iPhone:UIWebview open hyperlink in safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

In my app,I used UIwebview where I need to hyperlink some phone numbers,email & URLs.I did the following:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        credits.delegate=self;
    }



-(void)loadScreen
{
scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
 credits=[[UIWebView alloc]init];

NSString *Address = @"www.***.com/php/getjson.php?method=";


    jmax = [NSURL URLWithString:Address];

    NSData *Data =[ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jmax];


    String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * creditsHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" <font face=\"Arial\"><H3 align=\"center\"> Credits </H3> %@ <br>Phone%@</font>", String,phone];

    credits.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    credits.frame=CGRectMake(10, (frame1.size.height + 564), 300, 100);
    credits.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    credits loadHTMLString:creditsHtml baseURL:nil];

[scroll addSubview:credits];
}



   -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{


        NSString *urls=  jmaxString;

        NSURL *requestURL =[NSURL URLWithString: urls]; 
        if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ] ) 
            && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) { 
            return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: requestURL ]; 
        } 

        return YES; 
    }
```

Edited shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSURL *requestURL =[request URL];

    if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ] ) 
        && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) { 
        return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: requestURL ]; 
    } 
    NSLog(@"URL %@",requestURL);


    return YES; 
}
```

Got error in `NSURL *requestURL =[request URL];` with `Expected ; at the end` & `Extraneous ')' before ';'`

Comment: What happens if you replaced `openURL : requestURL` by `openURL:[requestURL URL]` ?

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that my shouldStartLoadWithRequest: function is not getting called

Comment: Please, can you post the whole class ? I suspect you forgot to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol ^^

Comment: No,I added the uiwebDelegate too

Comment: and your delegate, why didn't you put it in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: is shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is not getting called never .. or just when you click on a link ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi  shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is not getting called ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are alloc/init a new object of UIWebView in loadScreen function without set its delegate because you are suppose you did that in viewDidLoad .. you have to set the delegate after you define the instance "credits".

Comment: Thanks now -webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: gets called,but I know what I defined there is not correct.Ifound this code from some other questions but got error in 'request URL'  NSURL* url = [request URL];
if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}

Comment: just return NO in case the user click on line (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) and thats will make your app open the url in safari.

Answer (score 1):

just paste this line below where you create your webview credits in loadScreen method

```
credits=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
credits.delegate=self;   //Add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201264/open-link-from-uiwebview-into-safari-iphone).

If your `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method isn't being called at all, there's a problem with hooking up your delegate -- we can't really diagnose it further without seeing more of your work. (Are you sure it's not being called? Stick an NSLog at the top of the method body or put a breakpoint there in the debugger if you're not.)

Also, either you've stripped too much in the interest of brevity when posting that method's body in your question, or there's no connection between the parameters passed in and your logic for determining which URLs to open in Safari. I presume you mean to test the link the user tapped? That's in the `request` parameter.

Comment: I added some more code for your easeness.I want to open the links which I tapped in Safari.Please help...

Comment: If your `-loadScreen` is getting called after your `-viewDidLoad`, then your delegate isn't getting hooked up -- viewDidLoad sets the delegate one one instance of `UIWebView` (or perhaps does nothing, if `credits` is nil at that point), and then you create another instance in loadScreen. The new instance's delegate is nil unless you set it.